# Flex 3 using different services-config.xml files for debug and release build

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flex3

I've been unable to find a solution for this so either it's not possible, or I'm looking for the wrong solution. I am supporting an app that was written with the Flex 3.6 SDK and writing everything in Flash Builder 4.7.

Basically the issue is that we have two different services-config.xml files, one that is used when we debug an app (services-config-debug.xml) and the other is used when we do a release build (services-config-release.xml). What I'd like to do is to setup the system to do one of the following two things:

- Either have it setup so the compiler to use the correct version based on the button I click (debug or exprot release build)
- Or be notified someway (alert box, color change, etc) that I am using the services-config-debug.xml file.

We do nightly releases and I am getting tired of having to go into the compiler, switch the file that is used, export the release build, then switch the compiler back.

I am open to other suggestions and any help will be useful.

Thanks, Chris

Comment: Read this: http://www.mikenimer.com/?p=320 [basically, don't use a serivce-config; set the values at runtime.  For one of my client's projects; we load a config file at runtime and use that to set the appropriate end points for "Developer local machine" vs "Dev Server" vs "QA Server" vs "production Server"

Comment: I agree with @Reboog711; I never ever compile a service configuration into the application (that said, I don't find Mike's solution very pretty to look at). Nevertheless if you use a build tool like FlexMojos or GradleFx (which you should if you're building nightlies) you can easily set up build configurations for different environments. It's unclear from your question how you're doing the build though.

Comment: Come to think of it, I wrote this article some time ago that explains [how to create a build script for multiple environments](http://riastar.net/2013/03/28/gradlefx-multiple-configurations/) with [GradleFx](http://gradlefx.org/). You should have some prior knowledge of Gradle and the GradleFx plugin before you dive in though. I realize this may be a bit too different from your current workflow, but perhaps it'll spark some ideas.